# What is wrong with this thought experiment about special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity

If a (c/2)(m/s)*s long plane goes with c/2(m/s) velocity according to the observer on earth, and in the plane there are two light sources and observers that are positioned at both the tail and tip, I cannot understand how light traveling from tip to tail takes 0.5 seconds for the guy in the plane and much shorter for the guy on the earth, but from the tail to tip also takes 0.5 seconds for the guy in the plane and much longer for the guy on the earth. How does the observer on earth experience different times according to an observer in space with such an effectless change? It is certain that observers on earth experience longer or shorter times, which consume their lives, though nothing has actually changed. According to the observer in a plane, the observer on earth experiences different measurement durations with a change in direction. So for the observer on the plane, light reaches in 0.5 seconds for both situations, but for the observer on earth, light passing from tip to tail or vice versa takes a different amount of time, and it changes the time experience for the same event that both observers experience. Thus, according to occasion, the observer on earth ages more or less by the reference of time. How do almost the same events cause more or less aging in terms of different perceptions? If a plane goes in a circular orbit and you repeat that experiment continuously, the age difference of both observers will differentiate by the direction of light. So, for a full rotation, the observer in a plane calculates its relative speed to earth with the data of repeated time measurements. If light goes from tail to tip (direction of velocity) and if an observer in a plane measures it as 0.5 second and repeats the experiment until a full rotation is completed, let us assume that it took 128 seconds. The observer on earth will observe that the experiment has been repeated 128/0.5 = 256 times for a full rotation, and it took more than 128 seconds for sure. If the light goes from the tip to the tail in the experimental sequence, the observer on earth can measure the time of a full rotation in less than 128 seconds. For the same independent events, aging works differently. How does it even work? Does not that thought experiment disprove Einstein's assumption by itself?

Comment: *a c/2-meter long plane* What does that mean?

Comment: first, c/2-meter long doesnt mean anything. Did you mean $c(1\text{ second})/2=1.5\times10^8m$? Second, it's not clear what your problem is. It is "such an effectless change"? this doesn't really mean anything to me. Clarify what the problem is. Finally,  "but from the tail to tip also takes 0.5 seconds" its not clear what you mean by this - what is taking 0.5s here, how is it different from the movement of light from one side of the plane to the other in the plane's rest frame?

Comment: I tried to be more clear. Please reassess.

Comment: I'd suggest you read about the [Lorentz Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation).  *Properly applied* (which takes practice) this is usually the way to deal with most so-called "paradoxes" and confusion with special relativity.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of the Earth bound observer, the plane is moving. So the light emitted at the tail has to travel further to get to the center of the plane, because the center is moving away from it. Since the speed of light is constant, this means it takes longer (in the Earth bound reference frame) for the light to get to the center. Similarly, the light emitted at the front of the plane has less distance to travel, because the center is moving towards it, and so the light takes a shorter time to get from front to center (relative to the Earth).

Relative to someone moving along with the plane, neither the front nor back of the plane are moving, and so the light travels equal distances and takes equal times.

The flashes of light happen at the same time as measured by someone inside the plane, but at different times as measured by someone outside of the plane. Real experiments confirm this: it's not an illusion, and it's not merely a hypothesis of Einstein. This shows that time is relative -- there is no single absolute time. That's a hard concept for many people to grasp, but it's the most important part of relativity to understand.